# Creating a css flower with 5 leaves

Tags: css, styles, overlay, indicator

I am trying to create a css flower with 5 leaves - without any promising attempt.
What I am trying to create: 
CSS flower with 5 leaves where every leave can have three different states(small, medium, large). I have found http://rossmcneil.com/create-a-simple-css-raindrop/ so far - but I have troubel to overlay 5 shapes and change the size. Maybe I somebody can give me an advice how to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: So far I´ve got almost the same from the linked example.
Here is what I am trying to create: http://imgur.com/xqZ3QX4

Comment: I managed to get four leaves easy enough. http://jsfiddle.net/FkDDj/ Now to try and figure out that last leaf.

Comment: I really don´t have any clue to manage this with 5 figures. I am trying to find a solution for the 90° corners/edges.
Tried it without success with transform: skew(##deg) and with a pyramid instead of a rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a skewX and skewY to each rectangle.

```
 transform: skewX(value);  /* e.g. skewX(25deg) */
```

Here is what it would look like:

http://jsfiddle.net/SKbAz/2/

Comment: Thanks! I will use this in a prototype.

Answer (score 2):

Why not, it's fun:

http://jsfiddle.net/v5WxW/

mess with the angles as you'd like

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from{
        -webkit-transform : rotate(0deg);
    }
    to{
        -webkit-transform : rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.drops {
    -webkit-animation: spin 10s linear infinite;
    width            : 376px;
    height           : 294px;
}

.raindrop{
    background                      : lightblue;
    width                           : 80px;
    height                          : 80px;
    position                        : absolute;

    border-radius                   : 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius           : 100px;
    -moz-border-radius              : 100px;

    border-top-right-radius         : 0;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius : 0;
    -moz-border-radius-topright     : 0;

    transform                       : rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform               : rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform                  : rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform                    : rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform                   : rotate(-45deg);

    transition                      : all 2s;
    -webkit-transition              : all 2s;
    -moz-transition                 : all 2s;
    -o-transition                   : all 2s;
    -ms-transition                  : all 2s;
}

.raindrop.sm {
    width                           : 60px;
    height                          : 60px;
    position                        : absolute;

    border-radius                   : 75px;
    -webkit-border-radius           : 75px;
    -moz-border-radius              : 75px;

    border-top-right-radius         : 0;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius : 0;
    -moz-border-radius-topright     : 0;
}

.raindrop.lg {
    width                           : 100px;
    height                          : 100px;
    position                        : absolute;

    border-radius                   : 125px;
    -webkit-border-radius           : 125px;
    -moz-border-radius              : 125px;

    border-top-right-radius         : 0;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius : 0;
    -moz-border-radius-topright     : 0;
}

.raindrop.green  { background : lightgreen; }
.raindrop.yellow { background : yellow;     }
.raindrop.orange { background : orange;     }
.raindrop.teal   { background : teal;       }
.raindrop.pink   { background : pink;       }


.raindrop:nth-child(1){
    transform                       : rotate(-72deg);
    -webkit-transform               : rotate(-72deg);
    -moz-transform                  : rotate(-72deg);
    -o-transform                    : rotate(-72deg);
    -ms-transform                   : rotate(-72deg);
    top                             : 159px;
    left                            : 159px;
}
.raindrop:nth-child(2){
    transform                       : rotate(-144deg);
    -webkit-transform               : rotate(-144deg);
    -moz-transform                  : rotate(-144deg);
    -o-transform                    : rotate(-144deg);
    -ms-transform                   : rotate(-144deg);
    top                             : 110px;
    left                            : 188px;
}
.raindrop:nth-child(3){
    transform                       : rotate(-216deg);
    -webkit-transform               : rotate(-216deg);
    -moz-transform                  : rotate(-216deg);
    -o-transform                    : rotate(-216deg);
    -ms-transform                   : rotate(-216deg);
    top                             : 27px;
    left                            : 136px;
}
.raindrop:nth-child(4){
    transform                       : rotate(-288deg);
    -webkit-transform               : rotate(-288deg);
    -moz-transform                  : rotate(-288deg);
    -o-transform                    : rotate(-288deg);
    -ms-transform                   : rotate(-288deg);
    top                             : 98px;
    left                            : 108px;
}
.raindrop:nth-child(5){
    transform                       : rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform               : rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform                  : rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform                    : rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform                   : rotate(0deg);
    top                             : 147px;
    left                            : 76px;
}
```

Comment: Wow. This looks really good. Thank you very much.
Maybe you have an idea to create the white space between the drops?
This would be everything I wanted. 

Thank you.

Comment: Tweak the `top` & `left` positions in the `nth-child` rules

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that - but I still have problems to place 5 leaves correctly with the right angle of the rectangle.

Comment: There's 5 leaves, you're not going to be able to get them to line up :)  You need 4 for that

Comment: Looks like it would move ;)

Comment: @BernhardPoiss -- I was already doing that (hence the `transition: all 2s` css code.  I was making it spin and having the petals resize.  But then I realized that I'd need to change the pin location because the petals were all resizing from the top-left corner, so I got bored and quit

Comment: @cwolves I would be so happy if there would only be 4 of them wanted ;) Aprecciate your help - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation of a basic 5 leaves flower:

```
<i><i><i><i><i></i></i></i></i></i>
<style>
i {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0; height: 0;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transform: rotate(72deg);
  border-top-left-radius: 99px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 99px;
}
</style>
```

You can definitely fiddle with the angles.
Have a look at the result in this **[6 leaves flower demo](http://codepen.io/arnley/full/EaQRGV/)**.